# Schema.org and violating the search engine rules

Tags: google, schema.org

The Schema.org is a great tool to attract people. As I found from few sources, it doesn't provide any SEO benefits, besides the neat UI from search engines, though I wonder whether Google or any other search engine will ban website from excessive usage.
For example if site has more than 10000 articles and all they marked 5 star,
does this violate the usage of Schema.org and is it possible to get ban from search engines

Comment: Here is a related article: https://cognitiveseo.com/blog/6201/faking-the-serps-rich-snippet-hacks-penalties-author-removal-alternative/

Comment: @StephenOstermiller How old is this article? It seems way out of date but does not list a creation date, modification date, nor do the comments have a year. I cannot imagine this is from this year. Much of this does not happen anymore. Clearly, however, Google did not live up to it's own rules. "If it can be manipulated, we don't use it." Dumasses!

Comment: From what I can see is that Google will use any Google+ rating and not take a rating off the site itself anymore. Even then, there are algorithms that evaluate the likelihood of a rating being valid including simple calculation of odds and comparing the ratings with other trusted sources. Google says they do these things, however, seeing the examples from the link @StephenOstermiller gave us, clearly Google was not doing any of this at the time. Judging the language of the article, it appears to be rather old. Google is supposed to take data from trusted sites only and not directly. Cheers!!

Comment: It's inaccurate to say that Schema.org "doesn't provide any SEO benefits" at all. It most certainly increases organic results - Google often displays things like breadcrumbs and events that it picked up because of the Schema.org wrapped around the content. Even if this does not directly get your link into a higher position, searchers will see this added information and have a lot more incentive to click your link versus the two above it that are missing that information. In the recipe sphere, you're not likely at all to get clicks unless your recipes have ratings.

Comment: A more recent article: https://moz.com/blog/structured-data-for-seo-1

Comment: Google issues Spammy Structured Data penalties. They only ban rich snippets for the site and maybe cause all structured data to be ignored.